# Ubuntu not mounting partition on startup (fstab looks odd)

Tags: fstab

I've spent the whole night trying different solutions, but nothing worked (disks, manual changes, etc).

This happened after I resized my sda1 partition on gparted.

First of all, this is how my fstab looks right now:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/sda3 /mnt/sda3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I set it up on disks to mount it, but it won't boot up.

This is the error I get when I verify it:

```
   [W] recommended root FS passno is 1 (current is 0)
/mnt/d22c5008-1a64-4577-8eb7-e760f2f88326
   [E] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type
/mnt/4480B15780B14FE2
   [E] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type
```

How can I permanently mount those partitions, since disks is not working? I've seen different fstab formats, but mine is looking totally different.

Here goes an ss from gparted.

[image]

Comment: I understand that you don't try to boot from sda? That your `/` is mounted elsewhere?

Comment: run this report so we can see total configuration. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  But you should be using ext4 as that has been standard for years and not use NTFS unless dual booting with Windows as that will require Windows tools to make repairs like chkdsk. Also better to mount with UUID or label, not device like /dev/sda1.

Comment: @oldfred There WAS a dual boot with windows, but the entire drive is meant for Ubuntu now.     
I believe the UEFI partition is gone (it was a fat32). I will run the report when I am back.

Comment: This is the report [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HYHc4PSn36/)

Comment: @Jos you are right, I am booting from a USB to have ubuntu running and trying to fix this.

Comment: So I did as the report said and created a partition (fat32, BOOT, ESP). And now I got [this report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Wdwcd4wvf7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, like @oldfred said, I:

1. Ran boot repair
2. Generated the report
3. Created a boot EFI partition (my MOBO is UEFI)
4. Mounted my boot and linux partitions

That solved my problem and I have my OS back. Thanks, @oldfred.